# JavaScript Breaks a Text Box

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a control that is a date picker with validation using HTML5's "pattern" attribute with a regular expression. It works fine.

```
<input type='text' class='date-pick' name='breakEndIE' size='8' placeholder='01-03-2011' style='max-width:100px' pattern='^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(0[13578]|1[02])-                ((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)-(0[13456789]|1[012])-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])-02-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29-02-((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$' readonly='readonly' required />
```

However when I put it inside a script using document.write() it stops working. (Pattern always thinks there is an error in the formatting of the date)

```
<script>
            var ifFFOCHR = false;
            if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") > -1) ifFFOCHR = false;
            else if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Chrome") > -1) ifFFOCHR = true;
            else if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Safari") > -1) ifFFOCHR = false;
            else ifFFOCHR = true;

            if (ifFFOCHR == true) 
                {
                    //FIREFOX/CHROME/OPERA CODE HERE
                    document.write("<input type='text' class='date-pick' name='breakEnd' size='8' placeholder='01-03-2011' style='max-width:100px' pattern='^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(0[13578]|1[02])-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)-(0[13456789]|1[012])-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])-02-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29-02-((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$' required />");
                }
            else 
                {
                    //IE/SAFARI CODE HERE
                    document.write("<input type='text' class='date-pick' name='breakEndIE' size='8' placeholder='01-03-2011' style='max-width:100px' pattern='^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(0[13578]|1[02])-                ((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)-(0[13456789]|1[012])-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])-02-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29-02-((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$' readonly='readonly' required />");
                }
            </script>
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I have tried copying and pasting the  into the document.write() many times. It works outside it, but not in it. I have tried getting a friend to do it.
We tried it inside another script and it worked fine, it is just inside this script that it breaks.

Please help.

FYI: The script is to make certain code display inside IE & Safari and different code display in Firefox, Opera, and Chrome.

Comment: without diving deep here are a few notes: (1) pattern attribute is kind of new and a bit on the unreliable side (2) feature test, don't UA sniff (3) document.write is the devil, use with caution

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
As I said above, the document.write() worked in another (blank) script, it is just having problems in this one. So I don't think it's the pattern attribute or the document.write.
I'm not really sure about your feature test vs. UA sniffing point. But I'm not really sure how I'd achieve the same result via feature testing. Do you think this is the cause of my problem?

Comment: why are you using `document.write()` at all? there are so many idiosyncrasies associated with it and a ton of other alternatives that give you much more control... and no UA sniffing isn't your problem, it is just a really bad practice

Comment: document.write() seemed to work fine, and did the job in other scripts like I said. I wasn't really sure of the other alternatives, and wasn't even sure what the issue was.

Are you able to tell me why UA sniffing is bad practice? Or point me in the direction that is good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One strong possibility is that you have escape characters e.g. `\d` in your regex string. Those are treated literal characters when the pattern attribute is added inline, but the `\` are treated with a different meaning when placed in a javascript string.

Because you have now wrapped that expression in a string, you likely need to escape the `\` character, e.g. `\\d`.

Try writing your string out to `console.log` or calling `alert()` so you can visualise how your string has been interpreted by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a javascript programmer but if i delete the tag readonly='readonly' is function correctly in MSIE8.

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to be readonly in IE/Safari as the pattern tag is not supported by those browsers.